# Visual Studio Code format Java opening curly braces on new line

Tags: java, formatting, visual-studio-code, format, curly-braces

How can I get Visual Studio Code to format Java documents with braces in a new like?

i.e:

This

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
}
```

To this

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
}
```

Edit: Yikes!! Just remember .vscode/extensions folder. I went in there then /ryannaddy.vscode-format-0.0.6/package.json and changed format.newLine to true.
Thanks for the help. So happy!!

Comment: related formatting docs (including how to open a UI for previewing formatting settings results): https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-linting#_editing-formatter-settings

Answer (score 12):

To solve this using "Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat" you can use an Eclipse formatter file. This allows you to specify brace position very specifically for each scenario. For example, `formatting.xml` showcasing all "next line" settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<profiles version="12">
    <profile kind="CodeFormatterProfile" name="style" version="12">
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_anonymous_type_declaration" value="next_line"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_method_declaration" value="next_line"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_block" value="next_line"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_constructor_declaration" value="next_line"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_lambda_body" value="next_line"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_enum_declaration" value="next_line"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_block_in_case" value="next_line"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_annotation_type_declaration" value="next_line"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_switch" value="next_line"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_array_initializer" value="next_line"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_enum_constant" value="next_line"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_type_declaration" value="next_line"/>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Valid values are `next_line`, `next_line_shifted`, `next_line_on_wrap` and `end_of_line`.

And then in your `settings.json` for Visual Studio Code:

```
{
    "java.format.settings.url": "/formatting.xml",
    "java.format.settings.profile": "style"
}
```

See [this documentation](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Formatter-settings) for some usage details.

Answer (score 2):

> Launch VS Code Quick Open (Ctrl+P), paste the following command, and
>   press enter.
>
> ```
> ext install vscode-format
> ```
>
> Visual Studio Code Format will allow you to format most of your code
>   documents. The formatting is triggered by running your format command:
>   editor.action.format
>
> Place your braces on the same line or the next line:
>
> ```
> {
>     "newLine": {
>         "brace": true
>     }
> }
> ```

link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryannaddy.vscode-format

Comment: I have installed it before. and I can't find editor.action.format in my settings. What's worse is it format my C# codes with braces on the same line. >.>

Comment: I think it happens because of different code styles. In C# developers add new line before curly brace, but Java devs don't use newline before curly brace. That's code convention of Java.

Comment: The configuration settings in settings.json file.

Comment: This was my only hope and unfortunately it's been unpublished from the marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna use that in VS Code just add this line below in `settings.json`

```json
{
  "java.format.settings.url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fbricon/c5960a86f0a21405a61b79c0f1b4a0fc/raw/16b9b75077d08ae8b36706718a8393268d2ea5d2/formatter.xml"
}
```

Thanks to [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/fbricon/c5960a86f0a21405a61b79c0f1b4a0fc)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my formatter setting is in `.setting/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`.

Actually, [this](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Formatter-settings) article works, I've tested by creating a new project for comparison. I couldn't understand why is that worked on that new project, while my main project didn't. So, I compared any project settings that applied to each project, and I found that difference in `.setting/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` file.

[Location of .setting/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj99W.png)

My new project has only a compiler setting in that file, while my main project has compiler + formatter setting, that's why setting in JSON file couldn't apllied.

My solution is to change the value of formatter setting in that file with the same value from my exported xml formatter (I got my formatter XML exported from eclipse). Thanks.

This is my new project content of `.setting/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.methodParameters=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.8
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.8
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enablePreviewFeatures=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.forbiddenReference=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.reportPreviewFeatures=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.processAnnotations=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.release=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.8
```

and this is what's inside my main project:

```
...    
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enumIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.forbiddenReference=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.reportPreviewFeatures=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.processAnnotations=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.release=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.8
org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.align_assignment_statements_on_columns=false
org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.align_fields_grouping_blank_lines=2147483647
org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.align_type_members_on_columns=false
org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.align_variable_declarations_on_columns
...
```