# Visual Studio code undoing my method indents?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I code in Java and I like to have my curly brackets on a different line when I code cause it looks neater

Like this:

`public class Quicksort`

`{`

I had just updated Visual Studio Code to version 1.51 and now every time I code it resets the curly brackets back to what defaults for java, happens when I save too. I was wondering if this is a bug or if I've accidentally done something and can revert it?

I don't want it like this

`public class Quicksort {`

Comment: Seems unlikely from what you've said, but do you have a code formatter such as prettier installed?

Comment: I Think so you are using some extension for formatting code. You can change the default formatting by going to command palette and searching format and choosing the type.

Comment: Just tried to press ctrl shift p and opened up palette and saving by no format worked. But it doesn't work when I just press save. Any way to make this the normal?

Comment: @Lament please post all your installed extensions

Comment: @JavaMan Debugger for Java, Discord, Discord Presence, Java Extension Pack, Java Language Support, Java Test Runner, Language Support for Java, Maven for Java, Project Manager for Java, Visual Studio IntelliCode.

Comment: I searched the setting with the keyword `java` and `brace` and hope get the related setting, but found nothing. so i put a [github feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-pack/issues/500) to look forward to some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a starting point... this should work (according to some sources on the internet... but for me, **it doesn't**)
VS Code should be able to use an eclipse settings file.

Type "Ctrl+Shift+P" (opens the command panel)

Open "Java: Open Java formatter settings" (create the file)...

change

```
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_type_declaration" value="end_of_line"/>
```

to

```
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_type_declaration" value="next_line"/>
```

As a last step edit the java.format.settings.url in File/Preferences/Settings

'Inspired' by Halvor Holsten Strand's answer for [Visual Studio Code java format document braces new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823701/visual-studio-code-java-format-document-braces-new-line?rq=1)

Comment: Didn't work for me but thank you for the help nonetheless